# Is there any flutter packages that support Bluetooth on windows

Tags: flutter, dart

Currently I am working on a project that needs to have Bluetooth features in Desktop
But I didn't find any working packages.

Can any one suggest me the good packages ??

Answer (score 0):

Try those BLE packages,they are supported to windows.

https://pub.dev/packages/quick_blue

https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_blue_plugin

From quick_ble package have following features

- Scan BLE peripheral
- Connect BLE peripheral
- Discover services of BLE peripheral
- Transfer data between BLE central & peripheral

Answer (score 0):

check out this link.

https://www.tldevtech.com/best-bluetooth-packages-for-flutter/

From the link, quick_blue(https://pub.dev/packages/quick_blue) library supports Bluetooth features in Desktop from Flutter.

Answer (score 0):

You can use win_ble package.

This is specifically developed to work for Flutter for Windows. Also it's up to date.

Current version of it is 0.04

Answer (score 0):

You can use win_ble package.

This is specifically developed to work for Flutter for Windows. Also it's up to date.

Check it out here
[win_ble](https://pub.dev/packages/win_ble)